# Passing object information to cost function

Tags: c++, object, function-pointers, nonlinear-optimization

Here is the problem. I use minpack for non-linear optimization. The cost function has the following signature:

```
void cost_function(const int* n, const int* m,const double *p, double *x, int* iflag)
```

n - size of initial point
m - size of function vector
p - initial point
x - function vector

I have for loop, where i iterate through the array of objects. Each object contain input information for optimization function.

```
for(int counter = 0; i < num_of_objects; ++counter)
{
    //get information from object
    //call optimization function
    lmdif1_(cost_function, m, n, initial_point, X, precision, info, iwa, wa, lwa);
}
```

but in cost function i need particular values connected with current object. If cost function would be a class member, then the pointer will have wrong type, and it will be impossible to pass this pointer to lmdif1_.

So now i have a temporary solution, using global object.

```
for(int counter = 0; i < num_of_objects; ++counter)
{
    //get information from object
    //call optimization function
    global_obj = object;
    lmdif1_(cost_function, m, n, initial_point, X, precision, info, iwa, wa, lwa);
}
```

Then cost_function uses this global object to recieve needed information. But it's not good. What is the right solution for this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems like they broke the first rule of callback design: Provide a caller-supplied pointer-sized parameter through unchanged to the callback.

Comment: Maybe there are some ways, to solve this problem through static class members? I dont really have an idea how exactly...

Comment: A static class member is not much different than a global variable whose name starts with `ClassName::`.  Same advantages and drawbacks.  Only difference is it can be `private`, which is basically a global variable only accessible to certain functions (but so were `static` globals)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those `m`, `n`, `fvec` arrays can be class members, you could maybe use the `offsetof` macro to recover the address of the class.  (For how to do that, read [this explanation of the non-standard `container_of` macro](http://www.kroah.com/log/linux/container_of.html))

If they're dynamically allocated, it's harder, but you could allocate extra space in the buffer, and put a pointer to your class in front of the actual array data.